# Wifi Hotspot in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hotspot

I want to enable the WiFi hotspot in Windows 8 64 bit. Is there any software package or any default feature to enable it in Microsoft Windows 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press the Windows + R key combination to bring up a run box, type ncpa.cpl and hit enter.

When your network connections open, right-click on your Wireless network adapter and select properties from the context menu.

Now switch over to the Sharing tab and allow other devices to use your machines internet by selecting the first checkbox and then unchecking the second before clicking on the OK button.

Now right-click in the bottom left of your screen, to launch an administrative command prompt.

Now we need to set up the wireless network, this is done using the netsh command like so: netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=”NETWORKNAME” key=”Pa$$w0rd”

Where "ssid" is the name of your network, and "key" is the password you want users to connect with, its also worth mentioning that the access point is created with WPA2-PSK (AES) encryption.

Now we are ready to start broadcasting our network:

netsh wlan start hostednetwork

The last command you will need to know is the show command, it will tell you things like the channel you are on as well as the number of clients connected to your network:

netsh wlan show hostednetwork

Here's links to the above process encase your more of a visual learner:

http://www.howtogeek.com/112050/how-to-turn-your-windows-8-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/

or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pvK-6321ig