# How to turn windows 8 laptop into wifi hotspot?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, hotspot

I want to turn my Windows 8 Laptop into WiFi hotspot and want to use the internet in laptop through my Nokia Lumia 520. I use a USB dongle to connect my laptop to internet. I tried the thing as same as answered in below question,

[Wifi Hotspot in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/791088/wifi-hotspot-in-windows-8)

My mobile detected the WiFi hotspot, i am even able to connect to it through my mobile. But somehow internet is not working on mobile. Turned off windows firewall, reconnected and tried. Still no success. What else am i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

> Most USB Dongles nowadays have Built-in Wifi Hotspot mode.

1) The post you've mentioned in your question is to create hotspot using laptop's wifi card and share your internet connected to your laptop.
2) Most of them will *have* problem here and cannot connect to internet.
3) Instead you can create hotspot using the **Dongle itself** which will provide you with internet access.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this solution. First open command prompt to run the netsh utility below:

netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=your-ssid key=your-password
netsh wlan start hostednetwork

And go to Network Connections in Control Panel to set it up, then you should get an ad hoc connection for your Nokia Lumia 520.

Hope this helps! The method is from [How to turn into wireless hotspot](http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2013/02/turn-surface-pro-windows-8-into-wireless-hotspot.html)